# pyspark - No space left on device - How to optimize using union, cache, checkpoint?

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to optimize the following loop to avoid getting a disk space error when storing the following Pyspark dataframe.
`java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

Mainly I start looping across all buckets of a directory, then I join each bucket separately to another dataframe, add some calculations and union together.

Being pretty new to PySpark, I tried to include `.cache` and `.checkpoint`, but I feel the problem comes from the reshuffling of the dataframes in the union.

Any feedback concerning best practices and how to correctly troubleshoot this kind of case will be highly appreciated.

```
for i, user_group in enumerate(os.listdir(PATH)):
    # Open dataframe in bucket
    hda_i = spark.read.load(PATH + user_group) \
                    .dropDuplicates() \
                    .cache()  # Cache the hda_i DataFrame
    
    # Join bucket to external dataframe
    df_jpn = df_original.join(hda_i, on=['user', 'date'], how='inner')

    # Apply calculations (as new columns) to the joined dataframe
    Hmet_i = apply_function(df_jpn).dropDuplicates() \
                     .checkpoint()  # Checkpoint the Hmet_i DataFrame
    
    # Union all buckets to a single dataframe
    if Hmet is None:
        Hmet = Hmet_i.select(Hmet_i.columns)
    else:
        Hmet = Hmet.union(Hmet_i)

# Store all content together for a later visualization of results
Hmet.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite') \
          .save(PATH + fname)
```

Comment: That is not a memory error, that is a disk space error. This could be a full "temp" partition, or a disk that's just too close to being full to start with.

Comment: alright, being pretty newbie here. How can I control/minimize disk space errors? Is there some changes I could make in the code?

Comment: why don't you read all the data in one go? see [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup). you read one-by-one and keep on caching them without removing them. this cache isn't required at all if you're checkpointing it's result which is then used ahead.

Comment: The first thing to check is if you do have enough disk space, as clearing up some temp files or whatever may give you the room you need to get this to run properly. If not, then yes, it's worth checking what's going on here in terms of storage requirements.

Comment: @samkart many thanks! I Did not know about recursive loop, do you know how I can avoid loading files in the directory that are not `.parquet`?

Comment: you can pass a wildcard filter using [PathGlobFilter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-glob-filter) parameter

Comment: @tadman I see that I have some files in my temp folder. What are the best practices here? Should I remove all files inside temp before executing a new job?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, but you should be aware that temp is often limited in size to prevent it from using up all available disk space. If you need larger amounts of storage you might want to make a `tmp/` directory relative to your app, and self-manage that.